# Reverse loop fails using forvalues syntax

Tags: for-loop, foreach, stata

Why can't I use the `forvalues` syntax to loop in reverse? I *can* use `foreach of numlist` syntax to loop in reverse, but I'm confused why the `forvalues` examples below fail silently while the equivalent `foreach of numlist` examples work.

```
* both fail silently
forvalues j = 5/4 {
    display `j'
}

forvalues j = 5(1)4 {
    display `j'
}

* both work
foreach j of numlist 5/4 {
    display `j'
}

foreach j of numlist 5(1)4 {
    display `j'
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roses are red,

Violets are blue.

Try `5(-1)4`.

Hope it works for you.

Needed some extra characters to post, hence the poetry.

Comment: Dimitriy is right, but that still leaves the question of why exactly `forvalues` did not work for you. The answer is that it is never claimed that a `numlist` in general will work. The syntax diagram underlines that what is supplied must be one of four defined forms. The key difference is that `forvalues` is associated with code that can be very fast and that implies very simple rules.

Comment: (+1) I must confess I did not know that about `forvalues`.

Comment: I am not sure that it has been very widely explained. But if `forvalues` were only a special case of `foreach` it would be redundant, so there is a rationale for its existence,  beyond that of the simpler syntax.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov -- The -1 isn't necessary (although you're correct that -1 is better).

Comment: @NickCox -- Thanks. You're right, the help file never claims to work on `numlist`s.